# Kurtosis, bias, unbiased and statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics, kurtosis

I apologize ahead of time if this is too vague or meta to be a valid question.

I've been looking at Algorithms (Sedgewick & Wayne).  They define a class [stdstats](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdStats.java.html).  In that they define min, max, mean, variance and standard deviation.  Plus "population" (unbiased) versions of variance and standard deviation.  Reading up I find that there are two (at least?) forms of variance (and therefore stddev), one which uses the entire population (unbiased) count and one which uses one minus count (biased) (presumably this is a subset of a larger population sample).

- The difference between biased and unbiased is very small when the
  number of observations is anything other than tiny.  Is this a
  historical artifact of when computing a list of values was more labor
  intensive or is there still a valid reason to have these two
  varieties of variance/stddev?

After looking at this I started looking at skewness and kurtosis measures (largely because Wikipedia mentions these with regard to different random distributions and I thought they would be useful in testing code that produced these distributions).  Skewness wasn't too bad to figure out but because of the two types of stddev it required a biased and unbiased versions.  Then I started on the kurtosis measure.  There doesn't seem to be an agreed upon definition of how to calculate this value and I've seen little on biased/unbiased versions.  The only thing people seem to agree on is that it's a measure of curve "flatness".  I can confirm that different applications will give a considerably different value for the same data set when requesting the kurtosis.

- It seems that this would add a lot of confusion to understanding and communicating basic statistics.  If I give you a variance or stddev, the calculation differences don't seem too bad (given a large enough data set).  If I provide a kurtosis measure, how would anyone derive meaning from it?  Some applications subtract three from the calculated value (I assume for some sort of normal dist adjustment/bias).

Are there authoritative well defined definitions for all statistical measures or is it common to have (what seems to me) "loose" definitions that are more general concept than specific definition?

Is there a common set of statistical measures that can be used as general toolbox for "most" analysis?

Comment: The n-1 denominator version of variance is called Bessel's correction (because variance is otherwise a mean-square deviation from the mean). It's because of the fact that the sample mean is closer to the data (in mean-square deviation terms) than the population mean is, making variance estimated from the sample mean "too small". Bessel's correction exactly unbiases the variance (but not the standard deviation). There are many many posts on site discussing this issue. There are nevetheless various reasons why people might use the n-denominator version (or indeed some other denominator).

Comment: There are also posts that discuss several different versions of both skewness and kurtosis (e.g. see the two sample moment skewnesses in wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness)). As for deriving *meaning* from it, that can be tricky. The usual textbook interpretations that are offered are often (in fact usually) not really correct.

Comment: The simplest formula is that kurtosis is the average (or expected value, in the case of a probability distribution) of the z-values, each taken to the 4th power. The "-3" is no big deal. The "n-1" types of corrections are not helpful because they obscure the meaning and do not particularly improve the estimate. As for interpretation, "flatness" is certainly NOT agreed upon, as it is perfectly wrong. The beta(.5,1) distribution has an infinite peak but has negative excess kurtosis. See here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Kurtosis#Why_kurtosis_should_not_be_interpreted_as_.22peakedness.22

Comment: There are many good questions raised here--and that's the problem.  Some are answered elsewhere on CV and others invite multiple answers.  That doesn't fit well with our format.  But if you can pare this post down to ask one specific (as yet unanswered) question, that would likely work.